# first to third person mid text

Tags: third-person

I hope this discussion is still relevant but I only just had the idea to ask.
Ok so my story starts as a first-person narrator, however the narrator itself is a literal character. now I know it might seem a little strange to completely change the viewpoint mid narrative. I have a way of doing it that would work, or at least I think it will, it works in my head. I'm only asking if this would break the laws of writing? will it be too much for the reader?
I hope that made sense,
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change tenses in my first person YA novel?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35990/can-i-change-tenses-in-my-first-person-ya-novel)

Comment: What is the benefit of changing? What are you hoping to achieve that you couldn't in either all first or all third?

Comment: @Chris most of the questions that contain "is it correct to change the POV" can be answered the same way. Of course it's okay! As long as the reader likes it. You as a writer can do as you wish and as long as it makes sense no one will question it. Do beware it needs to be done right. I still think this is a duplicate question and you can find the answer to it if you search a bit through SE.Writing. [viewpoint] tag could prove useful.

Comment: If you still think your question is fundamentally different. Could you give us more context to your story? I have trouble understanding this sentence: "Ok so my story starts as a first-person narrator, however the narrator itself is a literal character.".